# DSNACICS stored procedure - Way to pass comp and comp3 fields in commarea parameter

Tags: db2, mainframe, cics

I have a question about passing `COMP` and `COMP-3` field data in DFHCOMMAREA in the context of the DSNACICS stored procedure.

If the field is `X(3)`, I pass 3 characters with leading spaces in the case that the data is smaller. However, if the field is say `S9(4) COMP`, how many characters should I pass in DFHCOMMAREA in case I have to send a value of `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, and not specifically to DSNACICS, a `PIC S9(4) COMP` field  in COBOL is a half word binary field, meaning that it occupies 2 bytes of physical space with the value represented in hexadecimal. A `PIC S9(4) COMP` field can store a value range from -32,768 (8000 in hex) to +32,767 (7FFF in hex).

However be aware of the `TRUNC` compiler option that you have in use. If a program passing the data is compiled as `TRUNC(BIN)` you can use the range of values above in the field. If however you have the `TRUNC(OPT)` compiler option specified and you move the value 32767 into the `PIC S9(4) COMP` field, you are likely to end up with the value 2767 actually placed in the variable, rather than 32767! i.e. not the value you expected. (That one has had me once or twice).

Here is a reference to a page in the doc that might be helpful  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.1?topic=data-examples-numeric-internal-representation

If you wanted to move the value of 2 into a `PIC S9(4) COMP` field, internally it would be 2 bytes represented (in hex) as 0002.